# Recursively compare each item from two lists, return new list with smallest items

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, pseudocode

Doing this in Scheme/Racket

The question is: Take two equal-length lists of numbers, then return a list consisting of the smallest numbers position by position.

Ex: `listMins( '(1 7 5) '(2 8 3) )`

returns `(1, 7, 3)` since `1<2` and `7<8` and `3<5`

I am new to functional programming and weak at recursion. I feel as though I am just missing some key pieces that I don't know how to tackle in my pseudocode, so that I can start coding this for real. (I tried jumping into code first, and it didn't work, so I'm taking a step back to pseudocode.)

PSEUDOCODE:

```
(listMins x, y)(
    (if !null A)
        (if > listAitem listBitem)
            (add A to newList) ;where do I make newList?
            (add B to newList)
        (return newList)
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually extremely easy if you use higher-order functions like `map`, especially since Scheme's `map` can accept many arguments, in which case it acts like a "zip" function. This means it's possible to implement your `list-mins` function in a single, terse line of code:

```
(define (list-mins . lsts)
  (apply map min lsts))
```

This uses some relatively complex machinery of Scheme/Racket, though, so it might not be very clear what's going on. The dotted argument, paired with `apply` allows `list-mins` to take any number of lists, but you really only need it to accept two, so here's a simpler version:

```
(define (list-mins a b)
  (map min a b))
```

What does this do? Well, `map` iterates over its arguments in parallel, applies a procedure to each set of elements, then produces a new list with the elements of the results. The `min` function simply returns the minimum of its arguments. To see what this looks like in action, here's what the above code is basically doing:

```
   (map min '(1 7 5) '(2 8 3))
=> (list (min 1 2)
         (min 7 8)
         (min 5 3))
=> (list 1 7 3)
```

Of course, it's possible to write this yourself, too, using recursion. Doing it manually would look like this:

```
(define (list-mins a b)
  (if (empty? a)
      '()
      (cons (min (first a) (first b))
            (list-mins (rest a) (rest b)))))
```

This is pretty much just unrolling what `map` does, and using `map` directly is much more clear (it expresses your intent to iterate over a set of lists), so it would be much more idiomatic than doing the recursion yourself. Still, if you're learning, then the explicit version might be more clear.

Comment: Extremely, extremely helpful.. I somehow was so tunnel visioned on the `car` and `cdr` part of my notes that I missed `map` entirely... definitely helps make this a lot quicker it seems. Thanks a lot for expanding the map min into the actual steps its doing.. that was very helpful. I was initially so confused on how to return a new array in the "middle" of a function.. and on the next problem I'm working on, I still am to some degree but I'm going to try at least another hour and a half on it.. Thanks again!